# One method with 3 variables

Tags: variables, input, flutter, methods, dart

Hope there is someone who can help me. And I hope you understand what I mean, because it is very difficult for me to explain the problem. ;-)

I have

int height

int width

int depth

a row with a minusButton - slider - plusButton  heightTextfield,

a row with a minusButton - slider - plusButton for the widthTextfield,

a row with a minusButton - slider - plusButton for the depthTextfield.

All the code is written out, so I repeat myself very often! The only difference is the var is height, width of depth.
This variables are shown in a textfield.

Here below is what I have done for the minus button, but it does not work.

```
  AnimatedOpacity minusButton(int heightWidthDepth) {
return AnimatedOpacity(
  opacity: heightWidthDepth == 1 ? 0.0 : 1.0,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  child: RawMaterialButton(
    elevation: 6.0,
    child: Icon(
      MdiIcons.minus,
      size: 15,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        heightWidthDepth > 1
            ? heightWidthDepth--
            : heightWidthDepth = heightWidthDepth;
        calculate();
      });
    },
    constraints: buttonSize,
    shape: CircleBorder(),
    fillColor: white,
  ),
);
}

//In each row I have instead of all the code:
minusButton(height),
minusButton(width),
minusButton(depth),
```

I thought that the heightWidthDepth would be replaced with the input variable height and that the variable height would get the value from heightWidthDepth, but it doesn't.

I have the feeling that there is a very simple solution, but I don't get it.

[Link to my app](https://www.invenio.nl/resin-expoxy/)

[image: Picture of the screen of my app]

Comment: So, you have three mutable variables which are intented to be interacted with buttons and you are trying to use these three variables for each button as parameter. But it's not happening as you want. Did i understand correctly?

Comment: Why not pass one more parameter with int 0,1,2

Comment: @Esen-mehmet, that is correct, I have added a link to my site were is an explanation of the app, hope that made sense. It works, but a lot of repeating code.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I don't understand what you ment. Sorry! The variable height is a value shown as a textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `Function` as parameter, instead of `integer`. In your `State` class, I think you have three variables to use in widgets. So:

```
int height = ..;
int width = ..;
int depth = ..;

AnimatedOpacity minusButton(Function onPressed) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: height == 1 ? 0.0 : 1.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        elevation: 6.0,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.remove,
          size: 15,
        ),
        onPressed: heightOnPressed,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        fillColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }

  void heightOnPressed() {
    setState(() {
      height > 1
          ? height--
          : height = height;
    });
    print('$height');
  }
```

Instead writing all widgets one by one, you'll just create `onPressed` function for each of them which are manipulates related `State` variables.

Example:

```
Row(children: <Widget>[
minusButton(heightOnPressed),
minusButton(widthOnPressed), 
minusButton(depthOnPressed),
])
```

Comment: Yes, thank you SO much, for your solution. I just have tried it and it works. I waited so lang to ask here and struggled so long with it. You make me think in a all other way. Thanks.

Just one question. I have a file formules.dart where I have all these functions. When I move this functions to this page, the system don't know the set state. Do I have to import something?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome @Margriet, I'm happy to help. `setState` is available inside `State` class and 'StatefulBuilder` widget. So, it won't work in blank dart file. Also you need to import `material.dart` file that's all. You should keep these methods and variables inside `State` class.